# When should an answer be flagged?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking at this answer right here:
[Unlimited desktop connections in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard](https://serverfault.com/questions/165395/unlimited-desktop-connections-in-windows-server-2008-r2-standard/165729#165729)

I'm wondering if it should be flagged as it advances a method which breaks Microsoft's licensing agreement. I'm sure this is something very few of us would be proud to have on here.

Or maybe a down vote is enough?

Is there an official position out there about flagging questions/answers/comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ergh. That question again.

There was an answer on there yesterday linking to some program which patched the system DLLs. Not particularly legal - so I flagged that answer, which promptly disappeared.

In my opinion, answers like that should be sent to oblivion - this is a professional site, for professional people. It's not very professional to suggest breaking the law, let alone posting ways to do so.

I also wouldn't like people to think of Server Fault as a place to go for advice on how to circumvent such restrictions that may be in software.

Comment: It'd be like people going to Super User asking "how do I get warez".

Comment: +1, I extend this to breaking network policy as well, not just the law.

Comment: I agree with Chris S. My pet hate is people asking for ways to circumvent restrictions imposed by their admins. What I hate even more is people answering those questions.